# On Minecraft, what do you do if the command is too long?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I copied a command then pasted it, but the full command does not fit in the command block. What should I do to fix it?

The command in question can be found here https://www.ijaminecraft.com/cmd/lucky_blocks
It is about 32700 characters long.

Comment: You should probably include the command so that users of the Arqade community can answer it or help you with a workaround.

Comment: I also recommend editing the question to include the command.  Without it, the only answer you will probably get is "Shorten the command."

Comment: It wont let me add the command in the question because it is so long. I could give a link to the website that has the command? A youtuber has done it in a video and it worked, so I'm just confused that it didn't work for me.

Comment: https://www.ijaminecraft.com/cmd/lucky_blocks is the link

Comment: A command block can hold 32,767 characters, so it should work using one of these..?

Comment: IjaMinecraft is pretty professional with his command creations, so it would be very unusual if he published a command that's too long. Are you sure there's nothing else in the command block and you copied only the command? Paste it into notepad and see if there's anything befor the first `summon` or after the last `}`, if so, delete it. Then press Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+C, then in the command block Ctrl+A (to overwrite anything if there's still something left in there) and then Ctrl+V. If it still doesn't work, then there's something wrong with the command.

Comment: Also, make sure you're activating it correctly, so that you're not just looking at an old output. `/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block`, then paste the command and then use a button or so to activate it.

Answer (score 2):

That command is for version 1.8.1 according to the linked page.  If you take a look at the [command block wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block) in the [history section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#History) of 1.9 it states:

> 15w33a Character limit is now 32,500 instead of 32,767.

The character limit was reduced after this command was created.  This command is 32,677 characters, which is over the new limit.

Even if this command would fit into a command block, there have been a lot of command changes since 1.8 which cause this command to fail.  For instance, it uses the [Riding tag which was replaced by the Passengers tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags#Entities) in 1.9.

He has reworked this command for version 1.11 which is shorter.  It can be found here: [https://www.ijaminecraft.com/cmd/super_lucky_blocks_1.11](https://www.ijaminecraft.com/cmd/super_lucky_blocks_1.11/)

However, I was unable to successfully run this command in 1.12.2.